# Facebook Like Box in Smarty tpl

Tags: facebook, smarty

i want to integrate a fb like box in a smarty tpl file. At this time only the iframe solution works fine, but there is no language support and that's why I want to use the new solution for the box.

The following code does not render the box in the tpl:

```html
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myfbpage"
data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/myfbpage">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/myfbpage">My Facebook Page</a></blockquote>
</div></div>
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Language of the Facebook Page Plugin is defined by the version of the Facebook JS-SDK that is loaded on your page

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=119010228291102";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This will render the Page Plugin in German and

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=119010228291102";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Will render it in english.

Just replace the locale in the URI to the locale you want to use on this page.

Comment: Thats true, but how can i insert the like box in the tpl? The code from FB doesnt work.

Comment: The code from facebook looks fine and should work, do you initialize the fb js-sdk on the same page? Without the SDK its not doing to work

Comment: Yes, I do, and ONLY this solution works in the tpl:


<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http://facebook.com/myfanpage&width=285&hight=200&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color=%23E2E2E2&stream=false&header=false" style="border: none; height: 200px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -1px; overflow: hidden; width: 285px; height: 220px;"></iframe>



But if you use the iframe solution, the language support does NOT work in the box cause it's old.

Comment: Frederick, you are right. The SDK was included in he header.tpl, but not on the tpl where the widget is set. Thanks!